# Spilling a cup of coffee

Tags: forces, experimental-physics

I've observed this many times when I spill coffee, It gets attracted towards the cup or the vessel. why is this so? Which is the force acting? 
(Hope you understood my question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reasonably certain it's surface tension
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension

Comment: How surface tension is the reason for this can you brief me a little

Comment: Surface tension is not sufficient to explain that! Adhesion is equally important. In the wikipedia article this is almost forgotten for capillary forces.

Comment: @George - Yes,Its due to Adhesive force.